# Animate RecyclerView items when resorting underlying collection

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've implemented RecyclerView and CardView in a new app, where I used a ListView in pre-L times. When I resort the collection, say:

```
            Collections.reverse(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This works fine but I need animations showing the user these changes.

Is there any easy way to do this? If not, can you point me to the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have stable ids, you can run:

```
Collections.reverse(items);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

which will give you "some" animations. You can do this for more efficient and realistic animations:

```
Collections.reverse(items);
final int end = items.size() - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < end; i ++) {
    adapter.notifyItemMoved(0, end - i);
}
```

Did not test the code but should be correct. Basically, for each item except last, you dispatch a move event for the first item towards the end of the list. Notice that first param is always `0`, because RecyclerView knows that when first item moves to the end of the list, next item is the first and so on.

This will have the same effect w/ doing a manual reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the collection 1 item at a time and call one of these methods in your RecyclerView.Adapter for each item.

```
final void  notifyItemInserted(int position)
final void  notifyItemMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) //I guess this one?
final void  notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)changed.
final void  notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)
final void  notifyItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount)
final void  notifyItemRemoved(int position)
```